# Detect onChange for RadioButton from a non-Null Group Value

Tags: jquery

I have an onChange event attached to a radiobutton group, but I only want it to fire when switching from a non-NULL state (to another non-NULL state).

Sometimes I have a case initially where both radiobuttons are blank (the field hasn't been set yet).

Radiobutton Scenarios:

```
( ) Option1   ( ) Option 2
(x) Option1   ( ) Option 2
( ) Option1   (x) Option 2
```

Code:

```
$("input[name='indicator']").off('change.indicator').on('change.indicator', function() {
            //... do my event
        });
```

I do not want the event to fire for Scenario #1, but it does for all three.

Comment: Can you please include the relevant HTML markup?

Comment: you can have a javascript variable for each of these radio buttons, with no default value or false or null. When it changes, update the value. This way you can check this variable in your function at each `onchange`. Test the value and continue only if the variable is already set..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) inside of a [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to determine if any radios within a given group are checked.  This demo throws up an alert if the event is fired.  It filters out the checkboxes for the event attachment if none of them are set.

```js
$('div[data-test]').each(function(i){
  var testDiv = this, test = $(this).data('test');

  $("input[name^='indicator']", testDiv).filter(function(){
    // filter the inputs. Returns all if any of them have a value.
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call($("input[name^='indicator']", testDiv), function(a,b){
      return a.checked || b.checked;
    });
  }).off('change.indicator').on('change.indicator', function() {
    // attach your event.
    alert("event fired for test " + test);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-test="1">
  <div>test 1 (neither checked):</div>
  <input type="radio" name="indicator1" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="indicator1" value="2">
</div>
<div data-test="2">
  <div>test 2 (second checked):</div>
  <input type="radio" name="indicator2" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="indicator2" value="2" checked=checked>
</div>
<div data-test="3">
  <div>test 3 (first checked):</div>
  <input type="radio" name="indicator3" value="1" checked=checked>
  <input type="radio" name="indicator3" value="2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So your HTML is like this I guess ?

```
<input type="radio" class="options1" name="options1" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="options1" name="options1" value="2">
<input type="radio" class="options1" name="options1" value="3">
<input type="radio" class="options2" name="options2" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="options2" name="options2" value="2">
<input type="radio" class="options2" name="options2" value="3">
```

I suggest you to implement this kind of functions for a NON NULL to a NON NULL change :

```
$('.options1').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked", true){
        //... do your event
    }

});

$('.options2').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked", true){
        //... do your event
    }

});
```